# Manually add computer to Android USB debug whitelist

Tags: android, debugging, whitelist

I have a Sony Xperia Z3 with Android Lollipop. Some time ago I dropped it and the digitizer cracked, so I can't use the touchscreen. Instead, I use a mouse. The problem is that when I want to use my phone to debug mobile applications, I have to unplug the mouse to connect to the computer, so I'm not able to use the computer to debug on the phone (I can't click OK on prompt). Is there any possibility to add my computer to the debugging whitelist using its RSA key?

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit confused as to what the problem is. What do you mean by use the computer to debug on the phone? You mention not being able to click a prompt but you also want to add your computer. I'd think if your computer was connected to the phone, you wouldn't need some way to add it.

Assuming you meant that you can't use the mouse to interact with the UI while debugging over an ADB connection via USB, why not use wifi ADB?

Comment: I tried few apps, but most of them need rooted phone (try rooting without touchscreen), while others need touchscreen too.

Comment: I don't get your touchscreen excuse. You can start wifi-adb before unplugging your mouse. The one by MetaCtrl does not require root.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a bluetooth mouse or keyboard to select the option when you plug into the computer.

I'm not sure what peripherals specifically the Z3 supports but I think a Bluetooth mouse should work.

Comment: If I had a bluetooth mouse or USB hub, I would use one of them. Unfortunately, I don't.